# Symfony 3 - Override bundle templates - prependPath not working

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` to `Symfony 3.4`. Currently I am using bundle inheritance to extend some features of the `FOSUserBundle` with my own custom implementation.

This works fine both in `Symfony 2.8` and `Symfony 3.4`. However, bundle inheritance is deprecated and would like to prepare my project for a future update to `Symfony 4`.

I know that I could move the templates I would like to override from `MyUserBundle/Resources/views/...` to the apps resource folder in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/...`. However I would like to keep the files in my own bundle (or src folder in SF 4) for better reusability.

Following a hint from another question I am trying to use a `CompilerPass` to add the path in my bundle to the search path:

```
// src/MyUserBundle/MyUserBundle.php
class MyUserBundle extends Bundle { 
    //public function getParent() {
    //    return 'FOSUserBundle';
    //}

    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        parent::build($container);  
        $container->addCompilerPass(new OverrideCompilerPass());
    }
}

// src/MyUserBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideCompilerPass.php
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $path = dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/Resources/views';
    $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition = $container->findDefinition('twig.loader.native_filesystem');
    $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition->addMethodCall('prependPath', array($path, 'FOSUser'));
}
```

However, this does not work. The templates are not found and Symfony uses the default FOS templates. The debugger shows this:

```
  // bin/console debug:twig WITH bundle inheritance
  @FOSUser    src/AppUserBundle/Resources/views/                                             
              vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/    

  // bin/console debug:twig WITHOUT bundle inheritance
  @FOSUser    vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/
```

So adding the compiler pass does not make any difference: When bundle inheritance is disabled, the templates are only searched within the FOS folder...

**How to solve this?** Is using `app/Resources/...` the only option or is it somehow possible to keep the files in my own bundle dir?

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2783#issuecomment-381139093

Comment: Sure, placing the templates in `app/Resources/...` will work. However the question was if there is an alternative solution which could be used to leave them in the own `src` folder. Prepending the path should work, but it does not. Question is why.

Comment: WTF man, I've linked exact comment... quote: In SF4 the template overrides must be placed in /templates/bundles/{BundleName};--- Nothing bout app/Resources

Comment: No reason to be rude... In the linked issue someone asked where to place template overrides and got the answer in `/templates/bundles/{BundleName}`. As described I know that this work (as will `app/Resources/{BundleName}` in SF 3). But this does NOT mean, that there are no other solutions to override this default behavior. Using the described compiler pass should be such a solution and the question is why it does not work. Or is there any official documentation (not just a comment) that states, that using the described folders is the only solution?